# In Notepad++ how can I use the Style Configurator to change my user-defined language?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

I've created a user-defined language for Notepad++, including all the syntax styling. It works well. (It's actually for Markdown, FWIW.)

I coded all the colors into the style when I made it. The background is dark. Main text is white, and certain lines are large, bold, and orange, for example.

**Question:** Because it's a UDL, it doesn't appear in the Style Configurator. Is there any way to edit the appearance of the syntax without editing the userDefineLang.xml file?

Sure, in "Define Your Language" I can right-click colors to use the default, but let's say I want to change my H1 tags to blue instead of orange. Because "Andrew's Markdown" doesn't appear in the Style Configurator, there seems to be no way to use it to tweak the colors.

Basically, sometimes I get tired of dark background, light text and want to switch themes ... but the theme don't support my UDL.

It seems like my choice is either "Code it in userDefineLang.xml" or "Be limited to the Global Styles list." Is that correct? Thanks!